# Not being able to receive push notifications with new distribution certificates

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp, apns-sharp

I am trying to implement the push notifications to my application that is currently on the store.
The old applications are working perfectly and receiving push normally with the same code on both server and app sides(OFF the sandbox).

However, when I am trying to create a production push certificate for my new application, I noticed that the push SSL certificate has changed and it seems that the development and production can now be received under 1 certificate.[image]

However when I send the created certificate to my server side and try to send push, I am not being able to receive any one on my device and we can't figure out why! (push are sent and received successfully my APNS Pusher application)
Note that notifications are working normally when creating a developer certificate and my app is in the development mode.

Any help to receive push on production mode? what modifications did Apple Change recently and what are the required steps that should I implement to my Server/App to make it work?

PushSharp version on my server: 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. By upgrading pushsharp library to 4.0.10 I fixed the issue.